# Prevent infinite loop due "PropertyChanged - events"

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm

I'm stuck in an infinite loop and I think the problem is the UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged from XAML TextBox.
What I want to achieve is this:

- I have 3 Textboxes:
- 1 -> enter a float and this triggers a conversion to hexadecimal value in textbox 2 (big endian) and textbox 3 (little endian).
- 2 -> enter a hexadecimal value in textbox 2 and this trigger a conversion to float in textbox 1 and little endia equivalent in textbox 3
- 3 -> same behavior.

But my problem is the UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged that trigger a series of event that causes an infinite loop or crash of my application.

My XAML CODE (View):

```
<Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBox
            Grid.Row="0"
            Grid.Column="0"
            Margin="5,0,5,0"
            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
            VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
            CaretBrush="#FF202020"
            SelectionBrush="#FF202020"
            Text="{Binding FloatInput, Mode=OneWayToSource, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
        <TextBox
            Grid.Row="0"
            Grid.Column="1"
            Margin="5,0,5,0"
            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
            VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
            CaretBrush="#FF202020"
            SelectionBrush="#FF202020"
            Text="{Binding HartInput, Mode=OneWayToSource, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
        <TextBox
            Grid.Row="0"
            Grid.Column="2"
            Margin="5,0,5,0"
            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
            VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
            CaretBrush="#FF202020"
            SelectionBrush="#FF202020"
            Text="{Binding GDCInput}" />
    </Grid>
```

My VieModel code:

```
public class FloatHartGdcConverterViewModel: FoundationViewModel
    {

        private string _floatInput;

        public string FloatInput
        {
            get { return _floatInput; }
            set
            {
                _floatInput = value;
                //HartInput = GeneralConverters.HexaToFloat(_floatInput);
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        private string _hartInput;

        public string HartInput
        {
            get { return _hartInput; }
            set
            {
                _hartInput = value;
                // FloatInput = GeneralConverters.FloatToHexa(_hartInput);
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        private string _gdcInput;

        public string GDCInput
        {
            get { return _gdcInput; }
            set { _gdcInput = value; }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Put some class level booleans to control whether an event handler should quit early or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are in the same class, you can write directly to the "_" private value for it, then throw your OnPropertyChanged().  Since you are not applying to the SETTER component, it will not be recursively calling the others.